# Digital Potentiometer 0.1 .. 10 Kilo Ohm

Tags: potentiometer

I would be very thankfull if you can propose to me a digital potentiometer with which I can have an electrical resistance between 0.1 and 10 K.Ohm

Comment: This is not on-topic on this website.

Comment: A digital potentiometer has a fixed end to end resistance.

Comment: If you are seeking a certain product, browse to suppliers like Farnell, Digikey and Mouser. They have ICs listed by functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use a digital potentiometer IC for this.
There are multiple manufacturers, here is one from Microchip:
http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/MCP4151_MIC.pdf

Comment: Providing an answer for an unambiguously off topic question just encourages more of the same hence my down vote.

Comment: @Andyaka 1) - Alexander already wrote in his answer that I shouldn't ask for products in the future . 2) - I'm new in the community --> so no need to be so rude

Comment: @BenJo - Andy isn't being rude at all. He's pointing out the long established rules of the site, which both you and Alexander ignored. Ignoring the rules is rude.